# Excel VBA: subs change automatically to private subs

Tags: excel, vba, private

My subs change automatically into private subs when opening a workbook. So then they don't work anymore.

What is the solution or the cause?

[image: example]

Comment: What happens if you move your Subs to a standard module instead of ThisWorkbook module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thisworkbook` is used for workbook triggers like workbook open etc.

You need to place the sub in a normal module without the `private` keyword

Goto the module folder visible in your image to insert a new module